# TSQL Stored Procedure: If Else Statement in Stored Procedure to Return 1 if calculated value greater then 1

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following stored procedure:

```
@Beginn Datetime,
@End Datetime
as
Begin
select  DATE,
IF((((SUM(ScheduleTime*(OkParts/100))/ SUM(PLannedTime)))) >1) then 1 else (((SUM(ScheduleTime*(OkParts/100))/ SUM(PLannedTime)))
from Rawdata where PartNo>0 and DATE> @Beginn and DATE< @End 
Group by DATE
Order by DATE DESC
End
```

However the procedure throws an error.

The calculated value is meant to be a percentage value. Due to incorrect user input, in rare cases the value can be as high as 250%, thus i want to return 1 (Logically the value can only be 100%), otherwise just return the calculated value. I have not yet found a function that sets a absolute ceiling for a value returned by a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

may this works for you:

```
@Beginn Datetime,
@End Datetime
as
Begin
select  DATE,
case when SUM(ScheduleTime*(OkParts/100))/ SUM(PLannedTime) >1 then 1 
    else SUM(ScheduleTime*(OkParts/100))/ SUM(PLannedTime) end
from Rawdata where PartNo>0 and DATE> @Beginn and DATE< @End 
Group by DATE
Order by DATE DESC
End
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cannot use flow control statement (e.g. if...else, while...) within select statement. You can use CASE statement instead.

```
Declare @Beginn Datetime
Declare @End Datetime

as
Begin
select  DATE,
(case when SUM(ScheduleTime*(OkParts/100))/ SUM(PLannedTime) >1 then 1 
    else SUM(ScheduleTime*(OkParts/100))/ SUM(PLannedTime) end) as ALIAS
from Rawdata where PartNo>0 and DATE> @Beginn and DATE< @End
Group by DATE
Order by DATE DESC
End
```